# Batch : encoding hell

Tags: encoding, batch-file

In DOS batch, I have to read file paths from a file encoded in UTF-8.

```
chcp 65001
:: read my file...
```

Now all messages displayed in my script are broken (accentuated characters appear wrong). So I guess I must revert to the previous `chcp` value.

When I call chcp all by itself, it spits me a nasty line, while all I want is the number :

```
C:...>chcp
Page de codes active : 850
```

How can I save the current codepage value in a variable before changing, so that I can set back to it after having read my file, and thus have my messages displayed in the console appear fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('chcp') do set OLDCP=%a
set OLDCP=%OLDCP:~1%
```

The second line removes the space before the number. Not actually needed, but I try keeping my values clean.